# Cant change resolution on MacBook Pro past 1920x1200

Tags: macos, resolution, macbook

I am trying to set my new MacBook Pro 15" to it's 'retina' resolution of 2880x1800 but for some reason the highest I can set it to in the settings is 1920x1200. I have tried holding the alt/opt key when clicking on the scaled but it still only shows the `select a text size` options with the highest being `looks like 1920x1200`. How can I manually select the resolution I am looking for?

The only way I have been able to get it on this resolution is by going full screen on a game on one of my desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because that is the retina resolution 1920x1200, only on the retina you get 2x the pixels of what you would normaly get from a display of that resolution (1920x1200) with 1/2 the space than what you get on the retina. Now if you want to enable the real native retina resolution type in google: how to enable full macbookpro retina 15" resolution, and you will fint plenty of third party software that will allow you to set your macbook's resolution to 2880x1800. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect. Found what I wanted.

Comment: @electrometro The answer was to google it? o.0

Comment: I tried googling around but couldn't find what I wanted. I guess having the right terminology for it was all I needed. lol